# linux command prompt display not working right when using upper arrow to show history commands

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, shell

I am trying to change my bash `PS1` variable to green color on the base name of current directory and white on commands, bellow is my `PS1` value:

```bsh
 ~ echo $PS1
\e[40;0;32m \W \e[40;0;37m
```

I found if using <kbd>↑</kbd> to get history commands, the command prompt will not display well

```bsh
 ~ ls
a.py  anaconda-ks.cfg  dotfiles
 ~ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
-bash: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa: command not found
 ~ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaals
```

here I first typed `ls`, then a long string of `a`, then pressed two times of <kbd>↑</kbd>, you can see that the command prompt is **not `ls` but `aaaaaaaaaals` which is concrete of `aaaa` and `ls`**.

#### What I have tried

I have tried change `PS1` variable to `\W` only, this time it works. It shows `ls` not `aaaaaals`

#### My question

What happens to this? Is there any thing wrong with my `PS1` settings?

Comment: You need to use `\[` and `\]` in PS1, see PROMPTING in bash's manual.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `40` in `40;0` is pointless since `0` cancels it.